# Value to be from a selection

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select s value from 3 options 
(40,80,90)

How can I do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like:

```
constraint chk_credits check (credits in (10, 20, 40))
```

You can add this to the `create table` or use `alter table` to add the constraint.